# NullPointerException in AndroidClient when connecting to the webservice

Tags: android, jax-ws

I get a NullPointerException in my Android client when connecting to the Webservice. I really don't know why...

Logcat:

```
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.webcentral.androidclient1/pl.webcentral.androidclient1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at pl.webcentral.androidclient1.GameAndroidUtil.callGameStatus(GameAndroidUtil.java:106)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at pl.webcentral.androidclient1.GameAndroidUtil.testGameWS(GameAndroidUtil.java:21)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at pl.webcentral.androidclient1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-12 18:46:55.062: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  ... 11 more
```

GameAndroidUtil:

```
package pl.webcentral.androidclient1;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class GameAndroidUtil {
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://game.webcentral.pl/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
    private static final String WSDL_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/ReversiGameWS/services/GameWS?wsdl";

    public static void testGameWS() throws SoapFault {

        String session1 = callGameLogin("Marcin 1");


        GameStatus gameStatus = callGameStatus(session1);
        System.out.println("Status gracza 1 " + gameStatus.getLastMove() + " " + gameStatus.isYourMove());


        String session2 = callGameLogin("Marcin 2");


        gameStatus = callGameStatus(session2);
        System.out.println("Status gracza 2 " + gameStatus.getLastMove() + " " + gameStatus.isYourMove());

        gameStatus = callGameStatus(session1);
        System.out.println("Status gracza 1 " + gameStatus.getLastMove() + " " + gameStatus.isYourMove());


        try {
            callGameAddMove(session1, 5);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Złapaliśmy wyjątek zgodnie z założeniem");
        }


        callGameAddMove(session2, 5);


        gameStatus = callGameStatus(session2);
        System.out.println("Status gracza 1 " + gameStatus.getLastMove() + " " + gameStatus.isYourMove());

        gameStatus = callGameStatus(session1);
        System.out.println("Status gracza 2 " + gameStatus.getLastMove() + " " + gameStatus.isYourMove());
    }

    private static String callGameLogin(String userName) {
        String METHOD_NAME = "login";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

        PropertyInfo propInfo=new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo.setName("arg0");
        propInfo.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        propInfo.setValue(userName);

        request.addProperty(propInfo);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            return resultsRequestSOAP.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception", e);
        }
    }
    private static GameStatus callGameStatus(String sessionId) throws SoapFault {
        String METHOD_NAME = "getGameStatus";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

        PropertyInfo propInfo=new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo.setName("arg0");
        propInfo.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        propInfo.setValue(sessionId);

        request.addProperty(propInfo);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception", e);
        }

        try {
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

            GameStatus gameStatus = new GameStatus();
            if (response.hasProperty("lastMove")) {
                gameStatus.setLastMove(Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty("lastMove").toString()));
            }
            gameStatus.setYourMove(Boolean.parseBoolean(response.getProperty("yourMove").toString()));

            return gameStatus;
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            System.out.println("Error adding move: " + e.faultstring);//można to ładnie jakoś pokazać na ekranie
            throw e;
        }

    }
    private static void callGameAddMove(String sessionId, Integer move) throws SoapFault {
        String METHOD_NAME = "addMove";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

        PropertyInfo propInfo=new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo.setName("arg0");
        propInfo.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        propInfo.setValue(sessionId);

        request.addProperty(propInfo);

        propInfo=new PropertyInfo();
        propInfo.setName("arg1");
        propInfo.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);
        propInfo.setValue(move);

        request.addProperty(propInfo);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception", e);
        }

        try {
            SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            System.out.println("Error adding move: " + e.faultstring);//można to ładnie jakoś pokazać na ekranie
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

And the problem is here:

```
            gameStatus.setLastMove(Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty("lastMove").toString());
```

Why is this so? This line is executed only if response has this property. If it has it, why the NullPointer?

Comment: You could add ``Log.d("lastMove", response.getProperty("lastMove") + "")`` before calling ``gameStatus.setLastMove``. You know, just to make sure.

Comment: Is it possible that the `request` has the key `"lastMove"` but the data is `null`?

Comment: What should this Log.d() change? Added it but no results.

Comment: @Sam Doesn't make sense to me but didn't see any other reason for NPE on that line.

Comment: @user208030 It will log ``response.getProperty("lastMove")`` value to LogCat for checking whether it's null or valid value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that Log.d("lastMove", response.getProperty("lastMove").toString()); is now causing a NullPointerException...

It is clear that `response.getProperty("lastMove")` is the problem. This means that `response` has a key for `"lastMove"` but the value itself is `null`... Simply use:

```
if (response.hasProperty("lastMove") && response.getProperty("lastMove") != null) {
    gameStatus.setLastMove(Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty("lastMove").toString()));
}
```

(If you control how the SOAPObject is created, you should find out why you are saving a null value in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

```
            gameStatus.setLastMove(Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty("lastMove").toString()));
```

The below line is null, thats why null pointer exception, pls add log n check it out
    response.getProperty("lastMove").toString()

Comment: Why all this talk of using Log for debugging?  It's a lousy way to find most problems, NPEs included.  Simply step through with the debugger and examine the variables.  That's what we should be teaching newcomers.

Comment: Each one of us has different ideas to debug the solution. I preferred log will help him.

Comment: It seems that

   Log.d("lastMove", response.getProperty("lastMove").toString());

is now causing a NullPointerException...

Comment: OK, let's do it the right way.  Put a breakpoint on that line and run your app until the debugger stops on that line.  Then hover over each variable to see which one is null.  Since you only have one, it must be `response` but using the debugger, you can quickly and easily determine why.